# Using gulp-uncss with gulp-sass

Tags: sass, gulp

My question is can you use gulp-sass together with gulp-uncss, or you can only use one. And if you can, do you need to keep them in different task's or do you need to use the gulp-uncss as a pipe inside that of the sass's.

Answer (score 1):

gulp-uncss is a streaming transform that is designed to operate on a pipeline of CSS files. Therefore, you can transform your SCSS into CSS in the pipe before running UnCSS:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uncss  = require('gulp-uncss');
var sass   = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('uncss', function() {
    return gulp.src('styles/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(concat('main.css')
        .pipe(uncss({
            html: ['index.html']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

NB: I maintain gulp-uncss.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how those two would play nicely together. SASS needs to be compiled to generate the resulting CSS, and gulp-uncss would either have to compile the SASS itself (doubtful) or be able to infer which rules would be used from SASS alone (likely impossible).